# Fabricjs dynamic pattern not working for SVG

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs, fabricjs2

I am using a dynamic pattern to fill a SVG image. It renders pattern fine but I am not able to transform pattern at runtime like mentioned in [FabricJs tutorial](http://fabricjs.com/dynamic-patterns).

Following is my code:

```
<div>
    <p>
        <label>Repeat pattern?</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="img-repeat" checked>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Pattern image width</label>
        <input type="range" min="50" max="1000" value="100" id="img-width">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Pattern left offset</label>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="500" value="0" id="img-offset-x">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Pattern top offset</label>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="500" value="0" id="img-offset-y">
    </p>
    <br>
    <p>
        <label>Pattern image angle</label>
        <input type="range" min="-90" max="90" value="0" id="img-angle">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Pattern image padding</label>
        <input type="range" min="-50" max="50" value="0" id="img-padding">
    </p>
</div>

<canvas id="c" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #ccc"></canvas>
```

Following is my Js code.

```
(function () {
    var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
    fabric.Object.prototype.transparentCorners = false;

    var padding = 0;

    fabric.loadSVGFromURL('images/bottom.svg', function (objects, options) {
        var oSvg = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);

        fabric.Image.fromURL('http://fabricjs.com/assets/pug.jpg', function (img) {
            var patternSourceCanvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas();
            patternSourceCanvas.setDimensions({
                width: img.getScaledWidth(),
                height: img.getScaledHeight()
            });
            patternSourceCanvas.add(img);

            var pattern = new fabric.Pattern({
                source: patternSourceCanvas.getElement(),
                repeat: 'repeat'
            });

            oSvg.getObjects().forEach(function (e) {
                e.fill = pattern
            });

            canvas.add(oSvg);

            document.getElementById('img-width').oninput = function () {
                img.scaleToWidth(parseInt(this.value, 10));
                console.log('img-width');
                canvas.requestRenderAll();
            };
            document.getElementById('img-angle').oninput = function () {
                img.set('angle', this.value);
                console.log('img-angle');
                canvas.requestRenderAll();
            };
            document.getElementById('img-padding').oninput = function () {
                padding = parseInt(this.value, 10);
                console.log('img-padding');
                canvas.requestRenderAll();
            };
            document.getElementById('img-offset-x').oninput = function () {
                pattern.offsetX = parseInt(this.value, 10);
                canvas.requestRenderAll();
            };
            document.getElementById('img-offset-y').oninput = function () {
                pattern.offsetY = parseInt(this.value, 10);
                console.log('img-offset-y');
                canvas.requestRenderAll();
            };
            document.getElementById('img-repeat').onclick = function () {
                pattern.repeat = this.checked ? 'repeat' : 'no-repeat';
                console.log('img-repeat');
                canvas.requestRenderAll();
            };
        });
    });
})();
```

Whenever I change any of the above range sliders then its taking effect.
Let me know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer. I have to modify the script as below.

```
(function () {
    var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
    fabric.Object.prototype.transparentCorners = false;

    var padding = 0;

    fabric.loadSVGFromURL('images/bottom.svg', function (objects, options) {
        var oSvg = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
        oSvg.set({left: 200, top: 50}).scale(0.5);

        fabric.Image.fromURL('http://fabricjs.com/assets/pug.jpg', function (img) {
            var patternSourceCanvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas();
            patternSourceCanvas.setDimensions({
                width: img.getScaledWidth()/2,
                height: img.getScaledHeight()/2
            });
            patternSourceCanvas.add(img);

            var pattern = new fabric.Pattern({
                source: patternSourceCanvas.getElement(),
                repeat: 'repeat'
            });

            oSvg.getObjects().forEach(function (e) {
                e.fill = pattern
            });

            canvas.add(oSvg);

            document.getElementById('img-width').oninput = function () {
                img.scaleToWidth(parseInt(this.value, 10));
                patternSourceCanvas.clear();
                patternSourceCanvas.add(img);
                oSvg.dirty = true;
                canvas.requestRenderAll();
            };
            document.getElementById('img-angle').oninput = function () {
                img.set('angle', this.value);
                patternSourceCanvas.clear();
                patternSourceCanvas.add(img);
                oSvg.dirty = true;
                canvas.requestRenderAll();
            };
            document.getElementById('img-offset-x').oninput = function () {
                pattern.offsetX = parseInt(this.value, 10);
                oSvg.dirty = true;
                canvas.requestRenderAll();
            };
            document.getElementById('img-offset-y').oninput = function () {
                pattern.offsetY = parseInt(this.value, 10);
                oSvg.dirty = true;
                canvas.requestRenderAll();
            };
            document.getElementById('img-repeat').onclick = function () {
                pattern.repeat = this.checked ? 'repeat' : 'no-repeat';
                oSvg.dirty = true;
                canvas.requestRenderAll();
            };
        });
    });
})();
```

The issue was that I wasn't setting SVG as dirty and wasn't updating the pattern with image changes.

I set svg dirty and updated pattern and then refreshed canvas and it worked